# sql, simple query to delete record from db

Tags: .net, firebird

I want to take users input as parameter to delete certain record from my firebird db.

So I have following code

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = txtDeleteField.Text;
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DemoAppConnectionString"];

            using (FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(connString))
            {
                using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM DEMOAPP WHERE CODE= @P1";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", code);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

                    int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (a == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Record deleted, ok!" );
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

This code produces error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll

Additional information: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 8
*
```

Comment: How can you delete with a `SELECT`?

Comment: Is this your actual code? `SELECT` doesn't delete records, the error seems to indicate you try to do `DELETE * FROM`, which is invalid (you should leave the `*` out.

Comment: typo :) It's delete, now it's updated

Comment: If it's `DELETE` remove the `*`. That's the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, `"DELETE * FROM DEMOAPP WHERE CODE= @P1"` is invalid: there should be no `*` in a `DELETE` statement.

Changing it to `"DELETE FROM DEMOAPP WHERE CODE= @P1"` should fix the issue.